# Is there a method to check the number of objects in an Oracle AQ queue?

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-aq

I know that calling  connection.dequeue(queueNam, arg, arg) listens to a queue. Is there a way to check if the queue is empty, or to see the number of objects in the queue?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a persistent queue, you could perhaps query the underlying `AQ$Queue_Table_Name` table.  If it's not, then I don't know of a way to do so outside of dequeueing each object in a single transaction that you rollback, counting the number of successfully dequeued objects.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/aq/package-tree.html) from Oracle the classes here do not have a way to check if they are empty or see the number of objects in the queue.

If you are referring to one of these classes, then there is no method for what you are asking for.

I came upon the classes from my first link from [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/streamsaq.htm).